# How to make two numbers equal by adding d to one and d-1 to another

Tags: algorithm, math, numbers, combinatorics, number-theory

You are given two positive integers a and b.
You can perform the operation any number of times.
**Operation is:**
Choose any positive integer d

1.Add d to a and d-1 to b.
OR
2.Add d-1 to a and d to b.

Are there any two positive integers a and b which cannot be made equal using the above operations?
Thanks for your help.

Comment: Since you got the answer, I just wanted to let you know that the code logic if you wish to write is also pretty simple.

Comment: vivek_23 Yeah I had written the code logic, and generated a file for test cases, was wondering why it is giving "Possible" for all inputs lol.
Suppose I don't know the fact that this is always possible, what will be the most optimized code which tells me it is possible or not for any given two numbers?

Comment: The most optimized code is the most intuitive one itself. See [code](https://ideone.com/DzYPfA) here. Since you said 2 `positive` integers, this is always possible to cut `1` from the bigger one and increment the smaller one by `d`. Sure, they will meet.

Comment: My code assumes that `d` can't change in the middle of the process as your problem statement doesn't say anything explicitly about it.

Comment: We can change d every time we perform the operation. And yes this is similar to my code, I also took a fixed value of d. Also, there is a problem in both our codes, the loop will not terminate if a does not equal to b even after adding d a number of times. The code itself assumes that we know that finally we will be able to make a=b and it will terminate. So we know the answer beforehand. And if the loop runs for an infinite time, it means that it is not possible to make a equal to b. But we do not have infinite time to solve this problem, we need a code that tells us is it possible or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Considering number difference: the first operation is equal to incrementing `a`, the second - to decrementing `a`.

If difference `n = b-a` is positive, we should make `n` first operations, if negative - make `n` second operations.

Yes, it is always possible for integers.

Comment: Thanks, I just wanted to confirm.